# How to use nested non capture groups in java regex

Tags: java, regex

I have a series of lines as follows (which can come in any order)

```
Distal latency   4.9 N/A N/A 4.0 N/A N/A N/A N/A 6.3 4.4 N/A

 % failed Chicago Classification  70 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1

 % panesophageal pressurization  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

 % premature contraction  20 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0

 % rapid contraction  10 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

 % large breaks  10 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0

 % small breaks  10 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

I want to eventually extract the line title and each value into a Hash as follows

```
Distallatency=4.9,Distallatency=N/A etc.
failedChicagoClassification1=70,failedChicagoClassification1=1,failedChicagoClassification1=1,failedChicagoClassification1=0,failedChicagoClassification1=1 etc.

and so on
```

My strategy to do this is:

```
1. join the words together by replacing the \s between words
2. End the joined word with a character eg : so I can then split each line into an array based on \s
3. Loop through the array adding the line title to each value into a Hash
```

Here is what I have done so far:

```
Pattern match_patternSwallow2 = Pattern.compile("(?:.*\\d+\\.\\d|N\\/A|\\d*){4,50}");
Matcher matchermatch_patternSwallow2 = match_patternSwallow2.matcher(s);

while (matchermatch_patternSwallow2.find()){
    String found = matchermatch_patternSwallow2.group(0).trim();
    System.out.println(found);

    //Join up the words so can then split by space
    found = found.replaceAll("([A-Za-z]+)\\s", "$1_").replaceAll("\\s", ":");
    List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(found.split(":")));

    for (int ff=1;ff<myList.size();ff++){
        mapSwallow.put(myList.get(0)+"MapSwallowsNum"+ff,myList.get(ff));
    }
}
```

I get no errors with the capture but it only returns an empty string at the System.out line.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you processing line by line?

Comment: I am taking the whole document as my string and then pattern matching on that. Doesn't 'while' just process all the matches therefore I shouldn't need to go line by line?

Comment: No idea, it is difficult to help without a reproducible example. Try [`"(?m)^\\W*([a-zA-Z].*?)\\s*((?:(?:\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?|N/A)\\s*)*)$"`](https://regex101.com/r/6pd9bD/1) regex. Then use the `.group(1).replaceAll("\\s+","")` as the key, and split `.group(2)` with `.split("\\s+")` to get the values.

Comment: Something like http://ideone.com/ZbOcLN

Comment: OK. Seems to work for most of the data. Please post as an answer and I will vote for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest the following regex to get each line that meets your criteria:

```
"(?m)^\\W*([a-zA-Z].*?)\\s*((?:(?:\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?|N/A)\\s*)‌​*)$"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6pd9bD/1)

**Details**:

- `(?m)` - multiline mode on
- `^` - start of a line
- `\\W*` - 0+ non-word chars
- `([a-zA-Z].*?)`  - (Group 1) a letter followed with any 0+ chars other than linebreak chars as few as possible up to
- `\\s*`  - zero or more whitespaces
- `((?:(?:\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?|N/A)\\s*)‌​*)` - Group 2 capturing 0+ sequences of digits (followed with a dot and digits optionally) or `N/A` followed with 0+ whitespaces
- `$` - end of line.

Once you find a match,  use the `.group(1).replaceAll("\\s+","")` as the key, and split `.group(2)` with `.split("\\s+")` to get the values.

See a sample online code:

```
String s = "Distal latency   4.9 N/A N/A 4.0 N/A N/A N/A N/A 6.3 4.4 N/A\n\n % failed Chicago Classification  70 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1\n\n % panesophageal pressurization  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0\n\n % premature contraction  20 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\n\n % rapid contraction  10 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0\n\n % large breaks  10 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0\n\n % small breaks  10 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0";
Pattern match_patternSwallow2= Pattern.compile("(?m)^\\W*([a-zA-Z].*?)\\s*((?:(?:\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?|N/A)\\s*)*)$");
Matcher matchermatch_patternSwallow2 = match_patternSwallow2.matcher(s);
HashMap<String, String> mapSwallow = new HashMap<String, String>();
while (matchermatch_patternSwallow2.find()){
    String[] myList = matchermatch_patternSwallow2.group(2).split("\\s+");
    String p1 = matchermatch_patternSwallow2.group(1).replaceAll("\\s+", "");
    int line = 1;
    for (String p2s: myList){
        mapSwallow.put(p1+line, p2s);
        line++;
    }
}
System.out.println(mapSwallow);
```